# How to extract and write to a file all rows in one column per unique value of a row in another column?

Tags: r, bash

my data looks like this:

```
      V1      V2      V3          V4 V5 V6              V7
1: chr11 9554978 9554979 rs114731977  0  + ENSG00000133789
2: chr11 9554978 9554979 rs374765884  0  + ENSG00000133789
3: chr11 9554977 9554979 rs796467675  0  + ENSG00000133789
4: chr11 9554976 9554979 rs796841057  0  + ENSG00000133789
5: chrX 15148554 15148555 rs2317411  0  - ENSG00000130150
6: chrX 15148775 15148776 rs2317410  0  - ENSG00000130150
...
```

what I want to get is (say for this sample) two files each containing a set of rs values from $V4 for unique value in $V7

like this:

ENSG00000133789.txt:

```
rs114731977
rs374765884
rs796467675
rs796841057
```

ENSG00000130150.txt:

```
rs2317411
rs2317410
```

some things I tried to obtain those values:

```
data%>%group_by(V7) %>% summarise() 
distinct_df = data %>% distinct(V7) %>% select(V7)
```

and they only return me the $7 column

I also tried this:

```
awk -F' ' 'FNR==NR{a[$7]++;next} a[$7]==1'  SG_ALL SG_ALL >ss
```

SG_ALL is where the data is,input file, 2 times I read first time it will take the count of lines and store them in array and second time to execute the condition if a count is 1 it should print line then only

But in the output I am getting just one line:

```
chr13 41545705 41545706 rs12429969 0 + ENSG00000150907
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option using the `tidyverse`:

```
library(tidyverse)

# Generate a data frame containing V4 and V7
df <- data.frame(
  V4 = paste0(
    'rs',
    str_pad(
      sample(1:10e6, 3),
      width = 6,
      side = 'left',
      pad = '0'
    )
  ),
  V7 = rep(
    paste0(
      'ENSG',
      str_pad(
        sample(1:5000, 4),
        width = 10,
        side = 'left',
        pad = '0'
      )
    ),
    12
  )
)

# Generate unique V7
unique_V7 <- df %>% select(
  V7
) %>% unique() %>% pull()

# Write V4 for each (unique) V7
for (cur_V7 in unique_V7) {
  df %>% filter(
    V7 == cur_V7
  ) %>% select(
    V4
  ) %>% write_csv(
    path = paste0(
      cur_V7, '.txt' # filename
    ),
    col_names = FALSE
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this solved my problem:

awk -F' ' '{f=$7".txt"; print$4>>f; close(f)}' OFS=' ' SG_ALL